# change value of an object with onchange jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

I have an object with the name of the filter that I want to change the amount within the object when a range slider changed

My HTML code is:

```
<input id="length" class="border-0" type="range" min="1" max="100"/>
```

and my jQuery:

```
function updateData() {
    var filter = {};
    filter.length = $('#length').val();
    return filter;
}

$('#length, #height, #capacity').change(function () {
   updateData();
   console.log(updateData())
});
```

Below code is not working and returns a number among 1 - 100

Comment: have you checked console for any errors?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Works fine for me?

Comment: This code does not give me the current value, updated

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work - I refactored your code a little and added filter to the outer scope so that you can update the object depending on the different types.
Updatedata now takes a type and a value and sets the object key and value depending on the target.

```js
var filter = { length:0, height:0, capacity:0 };
function updateData(id, value) {
    filter[id] = value;
    return filter;
}

$('#length, #height, #capacity').change(function (e) {
    console.log( updateData(e.target.id, e.target.value) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="length">Length</label>
<input id="length" class="border-0" type="range" min="1" max="100"/>
<label for="height">Height</label>
<input id="height" class="border-0" type="range" min="1" max="100"/>
<label for="capacity">Capicity</label>
<input id="capacity" class="border-0" type="range" min="1" max="100"/>
```

If you want the "live" value, see this Codepen example: https://codepen.io/juanbrujo/pen/uIqaw

Comment: but i need after change all ids all data return

Comment: I have modified this answer. check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/4cncuydd/2427/

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
filter["length"] = $('#length').val();
```

This removes the chance you’re setting the actual `length` property - but you do have to access the property like so IIRC:

```
filter["length"]
```

IMO it would be easier to change the property name, but I’ve tried to keep it as similar to your code as possible.